# Can I add a method on es6 class after it is defined?

Tags: class, methods, ecmascript-6, super

Method

```
method() {}
```

function

```
function func() {}
```

Above is just to elaborate difference between method and function.

```
class Student {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;  
  }
  method1(){}
}
```

In the above class, after writing the definition.
I want to add a method2 to the class, similar to the way method1 is there.
I can add a function like soo

```
Student.prototype.func = function(){...}
```

But I do not have a way to add a method on the same class. and inside function I will not be able to use super as that is just available inside the method.

1. Is there a way I can add method after the class is defined ?
2. So that I will be able to use super inside that.

Answer (score 2):

As has already been explained, you can only use `super()` inside the regular `class` definition.  But, long before we had ES6, we were calling parent method implementations manually.  It can be done using the parent's prototype:

```
class Person {
    talk() {
       // some implementation here
    }
}

class Student extends Person {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;  
  }
}

Student.prototype.talk = function(data) {
   // now call base method manually
   Person.prototype.talk.call(this, data);
   // then do our extra work
   log(data);
}
```

Of course, normally you could just declare all your methods within the `class` declaration so this would not be something you would normally need to do.

Comment: And even closer to the spec would be `Reflect.get(Person.prototype, "talk", this).call(this, data)`, but who make a getter for a method...

Answer (score 1):

Your snippet adding a new property to the prototype is only approach for adding a function later. One main difference in this case is that simple assignment like that will create the property as enumerable by default, whereas class syntax would create is as non-enumerable. You could use

```
Object.defineProperty(Student.prototype, "func", {
  configurable: true,
  writable: true,
  value: function() {

  },
});
```

to address that at least.

Unfortunately as you've seen, adding things to the prototype afterward does not allow usage of `super.foo`. There is no way for this to be supported, because the behavior of `super` is based specifically on the lexical nesting of the method syntax `method(){}` being inside of the class syntax. Methods added programmatically later on would have no way to know which prototype is the "super" one.